# cache installation of deps and afterwards build in travis

Tags: caching, travis-ci

Is it possible to separate the install deps and caching  from the build of the source code?

I have:

```
sudo: required
language: cpp

matrix:
  include:

  - env: GCC_VERSION="4.9" 
    os: linux
    dist: trusty
    compiler: gcc
    cache: 
      directories:
        - /usr/local/include
        - /usr/local/lib
        - /usr/local/share
    addons:
      apt:
        packages:
        - gcc-4.9
        - g++-4.9
        sources:
        - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test


# Install dependencies
install:
  - export BUILD_DEPS="OFF" 
  - export BUILD_GRSF="ON"


  - export CHECKOUT_PATH=`pwd`;

  - chmod +x $CHECKOUT_PATH/travis/install_${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}.sh
  - . $CHECKOUT_PATH/travis/install_${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}.sh

script:
  - chmod +x $CHECKOUT_PATH/travis/build.sh
  - . $CHECKOUT_PATH/travis/build.sh

notifications:
  email: false
```

Because my build takes too long (more than 50 minutes with building dependencies and the source code) I proceed in the following way:
I set

```
BUILD_DEPS="ON" # build only deps
BUILD_GRSF="OFF"
```

which only builds the dependencies and caches them, afterwards I set

```
BUILD_DEPS="OFF" 
BUILD_GRSF="ON" # build only source
```

in the `.travis.yaml` file which then builds only the source code.

This seems to work but is cumbersome? Is there a better solution to this? Maybe directly on travis modifying the `.travis.yaml` and make a new commit "travis cached, build source now". which will then trigger another travis build (which now builds the source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependency install script could look for a marker file your script leaves after successful installation in a cached dir and only if that's not found you would re-run the build.
That way you don't need any modifications to the travis spec at least.

Comment: thanks, that would be a solution.
so far my cache timesout (300mb tgz file) , cannot be installed because it takes too long, hm...?

Answer (score -1):

It seems travis can only cache in `$HOME`:

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6115#issuecomment-222817367